# Java: Regex to extract all non numerals AND leading +, if any

Tags: java, android, regex

Here's a string method I'm using in Java to remove all non-numerals from a given string:

```
replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")
```

Here's an example of what this would return:

```
Original string: $%^&*+89896 89#6
New string: 89896896
```

However, now I need to also retain the leading '+' sign if one exists such as in the case of the above illustration (thus, the new string should be +89896896). If this were PHP, I could have simply used a `preg` function with `(^\+)|([\d]+)` to get precisely the results I want. I am not sure how to implement it in Java (Android) though.

I came up with this

```
replaceAll("([^\+])([\D]+)", "")
```

But the results seem to be slightly distorted. Here's one test result:

```
Original string: +u +00786uy769+&jh6ghj765765

New string: +007876765765

Desired result: +007867696765765
```

What am I doing wrong with my expression?

P.S. I would like to avoid using the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes unless that were the only way out.

Comment: how does the second expression even compile? `"\+"` is invalid since you forgot to escape the `\\`

Comment: I tested it on http://www.regexr.com and it didn't say anything about any error.

Comment: Because most regex helper sites test *raw* regexes, but java Strings require escaping of the escape character `\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind based regex in  `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<!^)\\+|[^\\d+]", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yR4jL0/1)

If you don't want to remove dot then add dot inside the character class.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<!^)\\+|[^\\d+.]", "");
```

`(?<!^)\\+` would match all the plus symbols except the one at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\+(?!\\d)|[^\\d.+]", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE8pR1/1)

`\\+(?!\\d)` will avoid matching `+` is it is followed by a digit.